# Definition of Schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, schauder-basis

I have a definition of a Schauder basis but I’m unsure of it.

The definition I have is

A sequence $\{e_k : k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ in a normed space $(V, \| \cdot \| )$ is a Schauder basis if

1. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } \alpha _k e_k =0 $ implies $\alpha _k =0 $ for all $k$.
2. every $x \in V$ can be written in the form $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } \alpha _k e_k $(i.e. $ \lim_{n \to \infty }\| (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha _k e_k ) -x\|=0$

This definition to me seems to mean that the Schauder basis is countable.

However a theorem is ‘an infinite dimensional Hilbert space is separable if and only if it has a countable orthonormal basis’ .

This theorem seems to contradict that a Schauder basis has to be countable.

What’s the deal here?

Comment: horned space or normed space?

Comment: Why does it contradict countability of a Schauder basis? Uncountable orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space is not its Schauder basis.

Comment: The very fact that the "Schauder basis" is indexed by natural numbers means that it's countable. Is this the question you wish to ask?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Schauder bases are countable. At least this is how it's defined in *Linear analysis* by Bollobás (p. 37) and *Topics in Banach Space Theory* by Albiac and Kalton (Defn 1.1.1).
For a separable Hilbert space, the orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space can be taken to be a Schauder basis.

Note that if a normed space admits a Schauder basis then it is necessarily separable. Indeed, the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of the Schauder basis is a countable dense set. Thus, a non-separable Hilbert space (i.e. one whose orthonormal basis is of uncountable cardinality) does not admit a Schauder basis.

Comment: It was my (obviously incorrect) understanding that an orthonormal basis was a Schauder basis where the $e_k$ are orthonormal. What is an orthonormal basis?

Comment: @Ben In a Hilbert space $H$, an orthonormal basis is a set $(e_\alpha)$ such that every element in $x$ can be written as an infinite linear combination of elements in $(e_\alpha)$. Note that you can represent this as $x = \sum_{\alpha} \left\langle x, e_\alpha \right\rangle e_\alpha$ and only countably many of the summands will be non-zero. However, you may need uncountably many $e_\alpha$ to represent all the vectors in $H$.

Comment: I see, so basis in this sense is writing elements of the Hilbert space as a countable linear combination of elements $e_a $

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps to clarify some accidental "glosses" here:

In some contexts, a Schauder basis $B=\{v_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ for a vector space $V$ is a (finitely linearly independent) subset of $V$ such that the finite linear combinations of $B$ are dense in $V$.

There is no compulsion that the index set be countable, although if $V$ is "separable" in the sense of having a countable, dense subset, this will be the case.

Yes, since a sum of positive real numbers can be finite only if the index set is countable, in a Hilbert space the expressions of elements as infinite sums of linear combinations of basis elements can only involve countably many. :)

But that does not preclude the existence of Hilbert spaces without countable (Hilbert-space) bases. :)

Comment: How does this compare with the other answer here that says a Schauder basis is countable. Do different texts define it slightly differently?

Comment: @Ben, I don't know what to say about anyone's apparent requirement that a Schauder basis be countable... in part because there do exist Hilbert spaces requiring uncountable Hilbert-space bases (though these tend _not_ to arise in practice). "Defining" words in a fashion that makes it impossible to say certain things makes me uneasy. E.g., declaring that "group" means "finite group"... while, hm, there _are_ groups that are not finite? :)

Comment: And any of these Hilbert spaces with uncountable bases are not separable right? Due to the theorem above I posted

Comment: Right, Hilbert spaces with uncountable Hilbert space bases (such as $L^2$ of an uncountable set with counting measure) are not separable. They do not have dense countable subsets.

Comment: What is an orthonormal basis in this context? Just a Schauder basis where $E=\{e_a \} \subset V $ are orthonormal ?

Comment: That's what I'd think, but apparently some sources have other opinions. Bottom line: to know with certainty what anyone means by "Schauder-whatever basis" you have to ask them. Some risk that they'll be disdainful that you don't know their secret definition, but that can't be avoided. :)

Comment: I see. Thank you. That’s maths unfortunately sometimes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136216/discussion-between-ben-and-paul-garrett).